# Keyboard mapping fails since Debian 12

Tags: debian

I have just upgraded Debian 11 to Debian 12 and experience a problem with keyboard/character mapping:

(1) I have defined in

```
/usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose :
    <Multi_key> <period> <period>     : "•"   enfilledcircbullet  # BULLET
```

(2) I have defined in

```
~/.xsessionrc :
    # remap Menu key to act as Compose key
    xmodmap -e 'keycode 135 = Multi_key'
```

(3) the locale command shows:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US:en
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE=C
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

So, if I press Menu Period Period, the bullet should appear

This worked everywhere in Debian 11

Now, in Debian 12, it only works in 'Kitty' (terminal) and in a self-written Python script with 'PyQt6/QWebEngine':

[image: good]

but not in 'firefox', 'vim', and a self-written Python script with 'GTK 3'

There, the following happens:

- pressing the Menu key delivers an underlined  thin dot [image]
- then pressing '.' delivers [image]
- then pressing '.' again delivers [image]

(I needed to take photographs rather than screenshots, because the latter did not show the underline characters, nor the beam cursor)

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by copying my custom settings from

```
/usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose
```

to the newly created file

```
~/.XCompose
```

The two underlined dots still remain, though